# HOWTO make feedback on website improvement

Tags: plugins, open-source, components, product, feedback

In order to improve my website I was thinking to implement an ad-hoc component to provide feedback on tech or product developments that user would like to have, put to a vote this improvement.

Examples:

- https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/all
- https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/145075-xamarin-component-ideas
- http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/filters/top

There is products (preferably open source) to implement this or should I develop an ad-hoc component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Non-Commercial (Open Source)**
[Django Voice](https://code.google.com/p/django-voice/) (Python; BSD Simplified)
[All Our Ideas](http://www.allourideas.org/) (Ruby; Modified BSD)
IdeaTorrent (defunct)
[Openmind](http://openmind.sourceforge.net/default.html) (Ruby; GPLv3)

**Non-Commercial (Closed Source)**
[Google Moderator](https://www.google.com/moderator/) (Widget and API)

**Commercial (Open Source)**
???

**Commercial (Purchase Source)**
[VoxPopuli](https://www.eldos.com/vp/) (PHP + MySQL; [License Agreement](https://www.eldos.com/licenses/ww-free.php?PRODUCT=VoxPopuli))
[UseResponse](http://www.useresponse.com/) (PHP + Zend; [License Agreement](http://www.useresponse.com/eula_license-agreement))

**Commercial (Closed Source)**
[IdeaInformer](http://idea.informer.com/)
[UserVoice](https://www.uservoice.com/)
[UserReport](http://www.userreport.com/)
[UserEcho](http://userecho.com/)
[BetaEasy](http://www.betaeasy.com/)
CrowdSound (defunct)
[GetSatisfaction](https://getsatisfaction.com/corp/)

You could also use the voting system of one of the many StackExchange Clones, my favorite being [Question2Answer](http://www.question2answer.org/). For a full list of SO Clones, check out [this SO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones).